# Sometimes ntpq -np output garbled

Tags: ntp

sometimes alway find ntpq -pn output is garbled, have anybody seen this ?

```
$ntpq -np
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 127.127.1.0     .LOCL.          10 l  375   64   40    0.000    0.000   0.000
*100.xxx.11.73   10.143.35.200    2 u   39   64   77    0.397    8.849  10.888
+100.xxx.13.74   100.106.13.73    3 u    6   64  377    0.476    5.775   7.056
 100.xxx.33.124  .dj...          16 u    -   64  374   25.145   12.725   7.931
```

look before garbled is : .dj...
minutes later it back to narmal

```
$ntpq -np
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 127.127.1.0     .LOCL.          10 l  652   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
*100.xxx.13.73   100.106.33.124   2 u   52   64  377    0.397    8.849  19.528
+100.xxx.13.74   100.106.12.24    4 u   24   64  377    0.488    3.523  15.270
 100.xxx.33.124  100.106.12.24    4 u   17   64  317   25.145   12.725  14.965
```

Comment: what do you mean of the `garbled `?  for what?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your fourth upstream server `100.xxx.33.124` with the unexpected `.dj...` in the RefId field:

> ```
>      remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
> ==============================================================================
>  100.xxx.33.124  .dj...          16 u    -   64  374   25.145   12.725   7.931
> ```

Looking closely you can see that this server is unsynchronised to an upstream time source (it has a stratum of 16, the lowest possible). In this situation the Reference Id field is considered to be unspecified and should be ignored:

At Stratum 16 and above, the source is considered unsynchronized. The [`fudge` statement](http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.2/clockopt.htm) can be used to define the Reference Id for a timesource. So in this case I would suggest that the server is quite possibly using [its own local clock](http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.2/driver1.htm) and this has been labelled `dj`.

Here is one such (untested) example of using a local clock labelled as `dj`:

```
fudge 127.127.1.1 0 0 15 dj
server 127.127.1.1
```